# Angular Js - formating label when inner radio input is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm dealing with this case where I have a label tag wraps around the radio input button, something like:

```
<label>
     <input type="radio" ng-model="question.value" value="{{option.value}}">
</label>
```

The label tag is the one that gets formatted for view while the radio button is hidden. When `ng-model == value`, a certain radio button gets checked automatically and this is happening in my app, no problem at all.

The problem is, I want to format the label tag when this happens. Normally the label is formatted by an `onclick` event, but this is not an event so I'm not sure how I would solve this in JavaScript. CSS styling is not an option because it can't select parent element.

Comment: Do not forget to handle keyboard control if needed, label can be reached with tab key and radio button checked with space key.

Answer (score 1):

use ng-class

```
<label ng-class="{'class-name':question.value==option.value">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="question.value" value="{{option.value}}">
</label>
```

in CSS

```
.class-name{
   color:green;
}
```

Comment: simple but effective.